# Can we convert a SQL query to AMPscript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have this big query to convert in AMPscript. Is it even possible. Any suggestion or guidance would be helpful.

```
 SELECT count(*)
FROM properties_view
INNER JOIN markets on properties_view.market_id = markets.id
WHERE
(properties_view.market_id IS NOT NULL AND properties_view.address_1 IS NOT NULL
AND properties_view.city IS NOT NULL
AND properties_view.state IS NOT NULL
AND properties_view.zipcode IS NOT NULL
AND properties_view.lat IS NOT NULL
AND properties_view.lng IS NOT NULL
AND properties_view.property_status = ‘Active’
AND properties_view.syndication_status != ‘Never’
AND (properties_view.syndication_status = ‘Always’ OR (properties_view.syndication_status = ‘Auto’ AND properties_view.allow_syndication = true))
AND properties_view.unit_status IN (‘Notice Unrented’, ‘Vacant Unrented Not Ready’, ‘Vacant Unrented Ready’)
AND (properties_view.available - coalesce(properties_view.syndication_days, markets.syndication_days)) <= now())
```

Comment: Curious about why you would want to create a Query through AmpScript?  If the parameters are static then you are better off running it in Automation studio, and a UI SEND after. If the parameters are dynamic , then I would recommend SSJS

Comment: Are you saying you want to make this SQL query into an AMPScript Lookup, or are you saying you want to write AMPScript to create the query?  The more info into exactly what you are looking to do, the better for us to help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `RowCount` and `Lookup` or `LookupRows` with AMPscript but you won’t be able to JOIN any data.

I suppose you could wrap a bunch of `IF` statements around `Lookups`, but why when you can just use your query.